# JavaScript JSON Table Matching

Tags: javascript, database, json

I've been going through hell trying to figure this out, i'm sure it's not that big of a deal, perhaps i'm just tired from coding all night, but I could really use some help...

"users" is a database-like object containing user account information ( server-side, of course ), "get" is a function that returns an array of matching objects from the users array.

```
var users = [
    {
        name:"xymon",   
            age:19,
        pass:"mypass",  
        time:1364101200684
    },
    {
        name:"test",    
            age:19,
        pass:"x",   
        time:1364101200993
    },
    {
            name:"test",
            age:19,
            pass:"bleh",
            time:1364101200992
    }

];

function get(a){

}
```

What I'm wanting "get" to do is return properties that match the specified object (a) in an array, like so...

```
var matching_users = get({name:"test",age:19});
```

This would return the two objects in the "users" array because their properties match the specified properties in "get" so that "matching_users" would return as...

```
[
    {
        name:"test",    
            age:19,
        pass:"x",time:1364101200993
    },
    {
            name:"test",
            age:19,
            pass:"bleh",
            time:1364101200992
    }

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate your array and check each item for matching:

```
function get(a){
var r = [];
for (var i=0, len=users.length; i<len; ++i) {
    var doAdd = true;
    for (var p in a) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            if (a[p] != users[i][p]) {
                doAdd = false;
                break;
            }
        }            
    }    
    if (doAdd)
        r.push(users[i]);
}
return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function get(a) {
  var matches = [];

  for (var i in users) {
     var matched = true;

     for (var prop in a) {
         if (a.hasOwnProperty(prop) && users[i][prop] !== a[prop]) {
             matched = false;
             break;
         }
     }

     if (matched) matches.push(users[i]);
  }

  return matches;
}
```

Comment: if `Object.prototype` has a additional properties, you'll make 
redundant iterations

Answer (score 0):

```
 function get(a) {
 var result = [];
      users.forEach(function (v, i) {
           if (v.name == a.name && v.age == a.age) {
                result.push(v);               
           }
 });
```

Result will be the array with matched objects.